# Corrupted File from Uploading Bytes for Large Attachment Graph API

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the [Microsoft Graph API to upload a large file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http#request-headers) to a message. After uploading all the bytes of the file, the size of the uploaded file looks correct, but it's always corrupted (if I open the file, it will say it's been corrupted and can't be read).

What might I be doing wrong here?

```
$attachment[] = [
    "contentBytes" => $someFileAttachment->getContentBytes(),
    'attachment' => [
        'AttachmentItem' =>
            new FileAttachment(
                [
                    "attachmentType" => "file",
                    "name" => $someFileAttachment->getName(),
                    "size" => $someFileAttachment->getSize()
                ]
            )
        ]
];

// upload the file to the draft message
$uploadSessionResult = $createUploadSession($attachment['attachment'], $draftMessageId, $emailAddress);

$fragSize = 320 * 1024;
$fileSize = $attachment['attachment']['AttachmentItem']->getSize();
$numFragments = ceil($fileSize / $fragSize);
$bytesRemaining = $fileSize;
$i = 0;

while ($i < $numFragments) {
    $chunkSize = $numBytes = $fragSize;
    $start = $i * $fragSize;
    $end = $i * $fragSize + $chunkSize - 1;
    $offset = $i * $fragSize;
    if ($bytesRemaining < $chunkSize) {
        $chunkSize = $numBytes = $bytesRemaining;
        $end = $fileSize - 1;
    }

    $stream = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    fwrite($stream, $attachment['contentBytes']);
    rewind($stream);
    $data = stream_get_contents($stream, $chunkSize, $offset);
    fclose($stream);

    $contentRange = "bytes " . $start . "-" . $end . "/" . $fileSize;

    $uploadBytes($uploadSessionResult->getUploadUrl(), $numBytes, $contentRange, $data);

    $i++;

    $bytesRemaining = $bytesRemaining - $chunkSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issue before and this was the soloution for me.
I hope it helps you too.

after:

```
$data = stream_get_contents($stream, $chunkSize, $offset);
```

add:

```
$data= pack("H" . strlen($data), $data);
```

[PHP PACK](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to upload the bytes of the file using a cURL call to the Graph API. After adding that line of code and then calling upload bytes, it hangs and doesn't go on to the next bunch of bytes. Here is the uploadBytes function: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X_Zdcn5pWeNXg_L4ucXYIhi-NScETtxe/view It hangs as soon as I call the curl_exec function. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry it is not helped you. 
Maybe i have one more idea, with your original code. 
Try in your cURL func:

before you set
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $bytes

- ADD
  $bytes= file_get_contents($bytes);